# Python efficient way of writing switch case with comparison

Tags: python, switch-statement

I normally implement switch/case for equal comparison using a dictionary.

```
dict = {0:'zero', 1:'one', 2:'two'};
a=1; res = dict[a]
```

instead of

```
if a == 0:
  res = 'zero'
elif a == 1:
  res = 'one'
elif a == 2:
  res = 'two'
```

Is there a strategy to implement similar approach for non-equal comparison?

```
if score <= 10:
  cat = 'A'
elif score > 10 and score <= 30:
  cat = 'B'
elif score > 30 and score <= 50:
  cat = 'C'
elif score > 50 and score <= 90:
  cat = 'D'
else:
  cat = 'E'
```

I know that may be tricky with the <, <=, >, >=, but is there any strategy to generalize that or generate automatic statements from let's say a list

```
{[10]:'A', [10,30]:'B', [30,50]:'C',[50,90]:'D',[90]:'E'}
```

and some flag to say if it's `<` or `<=`.

Comment: Surely we must have a duplicate for these kinds of questions by now? Someone?

Comment: Python does not have a switch statement. Just use if,elif,else

Comment: Argh, of course this question here is also unsuited to be a good canonical... it just *had* to ask for a way to tell apart < and <=...

Comment: Related: *[Replacements for switch statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python/60211#60211)* [sic]. It also has the switch statement introduced with Python 3.10 (2021).

Answer (score 6):

A dictionary can hold a lot of values. If your ranges aren't too broad, you could make a dictionary that is similar to the one you had for the equality conditions by expanding each range programmatically:

```
from collections import defaultdict

ranges   = {(0,10):'A', (10,30):'B', (30,50):'C',(50,90):'D'}
valueMap = defaultdict(lambda:'E')
for r,letter in ranges.items():
    valueMap.update({ v:letter for v in range(*r) })

valueMap[701] # 'E'
valueMap[7] # 'A'
```

You could also just remove the redundant conditions from your *if*/*elif* statement and format it a little differently.  That would almost look like a case statement:

```
if   score < 10 : cat = 'A'
elif score < 30 : cat = 'B'
elif score < 50 : cat = 'C'
elif score < 90 : cat = 'D'
else            : cat = 'E'
```

To avoid repeating `score <`, you could define a case function and use it with the value:

```
score = 43
case = lambda x: score < x
if   case(10): cat = "A"
elif case(30): cat = "B"
elif case(50): cat = "C"
elif case(90): cat = "D"
else         : cat = "E"
print (cat) # 'C'
```

You could generalize this by creating a switch function that returns a "case" function that applies to the test value with a generic comparison pattern:

```
def switch(value):
    def case(check,lessThan=None):
        if lessThan is not None:
            return (check is None or check <= value) and value < lessThan
        if type(value) == type(check): return value == check
        if isinstance(value,type(case)): return check(value)
        return value in check
    return case
```

This generic version allows all sorts of combinations:

```
score = 35
case = switch(score)
if   case(0,10)         : cat = "A"
elif case([10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]):
                          cat = "B"
elif score < 30         : cat = "B"
elif case(30) \
  or case(range(31,50)) : cat = 'C'
elif case(50,90)        : cat = 'D'
else                    : cat = "E"
print(cat) # 'C'
```

And there is yet another way using a lambda function when all you need to do is return a value:

```
score = 41
case  = lambda x,v: v if score<x else None
cat   = case(10,'A') or case(20,'B') or case(30,'C') or case(50,'D') or 'E'
print(cat) # "D"
```

This last one can also be expressed using a list comprehension and a mapping table:

```
mapping = [(10,'A'),(30,'B'),(50,'C'),(90,'D')]
scoreCat = lambda s: next( (L for x,L in mapping if s<x),"E" )

score = 37
cat = scoreCat(score)
print(cat) #"D"
```

More specifically to the question, a generalized solution can be created using a setup function that returns a mapping function in accordance with your parameters:

```
def rangeMap(*breaks,inclusive=False):
    default = breaks[-1] if len(breaks)&1 else None
    breaks  = list(zip(breaks[::2],breaks[1::2]))
    def mapValueLT(value):
        return next( (tag for tag,bound in breaks if value<bound), default)
    def mapValueLE(value):
        return next( (tag for tag,bound in breaks if value<=bound), default)
    return mapValueLE if inclusive else mapValueLT

scoreToCategory = rangeMap('A',10,'B',30,'C',50,'D',90,'E')

print(scoreToCategory(53)) # D
print(scoreToCategory(30)) # C

scoreToCategoryLE = rangeMap('A',10,'B',30,'C',50,'D',90,'E',inclusive=True)

print(scoreToCategoryLE(30)) # B
```

*Note that with a little more work you can improve the performance of the returned function using the *[bisect](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/bisect.html)* module.*

Answer (score 5):

Python 3.10 introduced `match`-`case` (basically  `switch`) and you can use it as

```
def check_number(no):
  match no:
    case 0:
      return 'zero'
    case 1:
      return 'one'
    case 2:
      return 'two'
    case _:
      return "Invalid num"
```

This is something that I tried for an example.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/bisect.html) module can be used for such categorization problem. In particular, the documentation offers an [example](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/bisect.html#examples) which solves a problem very similar to yours.

Here is the same example adapted to your use case. The function returns two values: the letter grade and a `bool` flag which indicates if the match was exact.

```
from bisect import bisect_left

grades = "ABCDE"
breakpoints = [10, 30, 50, 90, 100]

def grade(score):
          index = bisect_left(breakpoints, score)
          exact = score == breakpoints[index]
          grade = grades[index]
          return grade, exact

grade(10) # 'A', True
grade(15) # 'B', False
```

In the above, I assumed that your last breakpoint was `100` for `E`. If you truly do not want an upper bound, notice that you can replace `100` by `math.inf` to keep the code working.

Answer (score 2):

For your particular case an efficient approach to convert a score to a grade in *O(1)* time complexity would be to use 100 minus the score divided by 10 as a string index to obtain the letter grade:

```
def get_grade(score):
    return 'EDDDDCCBBAA'[(100 - score) // 10]
```

so that:

```
print(get_grade(100))
print(get_grade(91))
print(get_grade(90))
print(get_grade(50))
print(get_grade(30))
print(get_grade(10))
print(get_grade(0))
```

outputs:

```
E
E
D
C
B
A
A
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a strategy, but not quite as clean as human thought patterns.  First some notes:

- There are other questions dealing with "Python switch"; I'll assume that you consulted them already and eliminated those solutions from consideration.
- The structure you posted is *not* a `list`; it's an invalid attempt at a `dict`. Keys must be hashable; the lists you give are not valid keys.
- You have two separate types of comparison here: exact match to the lower bound and range containment.

That said, I'll keep the concept of a look-up table, but we'll drop it to a low common denominator to make it easy to understand and alter for other considerations.

```
low = [10, 30, 50, 90]
grade = "ABCDE"

for idx, bkpt in enumerate(low):
    if score <= bkpt:
        exact = (score == bkpt)
        break

cat = grade[idx]
```

`exact` is the flag you requested.

Answer (score 0):

Python had (was added in python 3.10, hat-tip Peter Mortensen) no case statement. Just write a long series of *elifs*.

```py
if score <= 10:
  return 'A'
if score <= 30:
  return 'B'
if score <= 50:
  return 'C'
if score <= 90:
  return 'D'
return 'E'
```

Stuff, like look it up in a dictionary, sounds great, but really, it's too slow. *elifs* beat them all.

Comment: A switch statement was introduced [with Python 3.10 (2021)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python/60211#60211).

Answer (score -1):

```
low = [10,30,50,70,90]
gradE = "FEDCBA"

def grade(score):
    for i,b in enumerate(low):
        #if score < b:   # 0--9F,10-29E,30-49D,50-69C,70-89B,90-100A Easy
        if score <= b:   # 0-10F,11-30E,31-50D,51-70C,71-90B,91-100A Taff
            return gradE[i]
    else:return gradE[-1]

for score in range(0,101):
    print(score,grade(score))
```